# Items in order of repetition

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want method `repeated` to take a string and return an array of its repeated characters in the order they are repeated. Case sensitivity applies. In this example,

```
repeated("abba") # => ["b", "a"]
```

`"b"` is repeated before `"a"` is. Another example:

```
repeated("limbojackassin the garden") # => ["a", "s", "i", " ", "e", "n"]
```

works like this:

```
limbojackassin the garden 
      |--^                "a"
          |^              "s"
 |----------^             "i"
              |---^       " "
                    *     "a" ignored
                 |-----^  "e"
             |----------^ "n"
```

I have this method.

```
def repeated(str)
  puts str.chars.select{|i| str.count(i) > 1}.uniq
end
```

which works unexpectedly:

```
repeated("limbojackassin the garden")
# => ["i", "a", "s", "n", " ", "e"]
# => expected ["a", "s", "i", " ", "e", "n"]
repeated("Pippi")
# => ["i", "p"]
# => expected ["p", "i"]
repeated("apple")
# => as expected ["p"]
```

How could one check the distances between the array's item indexes?

Comment: In `Pippi`, lowercase `i` appears before lowercase `p` - the code has correctly returned `["i","p"]` - why you think answer is wrong?  Same with other examples as well - code is doing what it is supposed to do

Comment: I think its the distance between the items,the pair pp comes before ii

Comment: He means the character first repeated, this is, first character that appears twice.
In "Pippi" p is first repeated. Demo: you find a 'P', next you find an 'i', then you find a 'p', then another 'p' so 'p' is the first repeated character, note that you haven't found the other 'i' yet.

Comment: Looks like your problem statement is incomplete - unless you state that clearly and also code for it - you will not get right output from your code

Comment: @owade I have posted a possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using the index with [`Enumerable#each_with_index()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

The `select()` rejects all first occurances of characters since `index()` returns the first occurance.

```
def repeated(str)
  puts str.chars.each_with_index
                .select { |c,i| i != str.index(c) }
                .map(&:first)
                .uniq
end
```

Alternativly to `select()` you can use `reject  { |c,i| i == str.index(c) }`. Maybe it's more expressive.

**Update**: Insprired by Stefan's answer you can drop the `map()` method when using [`Enumerator#with_index()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) instead of `Enumerable#each_with_index()` since Ruby 1.9.

```
def repeated(str)
  p str.chars.reject
             .with_index { |c,i| i == str.index(c) }
             .uniq
end
```

Comment: Works fine now.  Best answer!

Comment: I had the same idea, but you accomplished it better.

Comment: This one is pretty neat.

Answer (score 3):

```
def repeated(str)
  puts(str.each_char.with_object([{}, []]) do
    |c, (h, a)| h[c] ? a.push(c) : h.store(c, true)
  end.last.uniq)
end
```

Comment: The requirement to `puts` the output is making it difficult to read. Somehow, beginners tend to write a method that `puts` something rather than returning that value.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on your code:

```
def repeated(str)
  str.each_char.select.with_index { |c, i| str[0, i].count(c) == 1 }
end
```

For each character, it [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-count)s the character in the substring before the character. If the count is 1, the character is [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)-ed.

As noted by Cary Swoveland, this creates and scans an intermediate string for each character. I'd use a variation of [sawa's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182348/477037) if efficiency was important:

```
def repeated(str)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char.with_object([]) do |c, a|
    a << c if h[c] == 1
    h[c] += 1
  end
end
```

This traverses the string via [`each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-each_char) and counts each character using a hash `h`. If a character is encountered a second time (count value is 1), it is added to an array `a` which is implicitly returned at the end by [`each_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).

I've just realized that you can use `select` instead of `with_object`:

```
def repeated(str)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char.select { |c| (h[c] += 1) == 2 }
end
```

Comment: Clever, but not very efficient, considering that you create a lot of temporary arrays and keep counting for characters after two have been found.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it creates temporary strings actually, but your point is valid. I've added another - more efficient - version.

Comment: So that's what @sawa was doing. :-). I suggested something similar, but I prefer your revision as it's probably a bit faster. On the other hand, I don't have an array and append to it...

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Jack be nimble, jack be quick, Jack jumped over the candle stick"

require 'set'

read1, read2 = Set.new, Set.new
str.each_char { |c| read2.add(c) unless read1.add?(c) }
read2.to_a
  #=> [" ", "b", "e", "a", "c", "k", "i", ",", "J", "j", "u", "m", "n", "d", "l", "t"]
```

An attempt is made to add each character to `read1`. If the character can be added, it is the first time that character has been encountered. If the character cannot be added to `read1` (because `read1` already contains the character), an attempt is made to add it to `read2`. Whether `read2` already contains that character is unimportant; all that matters is that `read2` will contain that character after the attempt is made to add it.

Therefore, after all characters have been enumerated, `read2` will contain the characters that appear more than once in the proper order.

Edit: I wish to thank @Stefan for pointing out that I did not need `read2.include?(c) ||` following `unless`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the call to `read2.include?(c)` is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. Even tighter! btw, my reaction when I see that conditional clause from you: :-D

Answer (score 2):

**Ladies and gentlemen, start your engines!**

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

def sschmeck(str)
  str.chars.each_with_index.select { |c,i| i != str.index(c) }.map(&:first).uniq
end

def drenmi(str)
  str.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }).
      with_index { |(c, m), i| m[c] << i }.select { |_, v| v.length > 1 }.
      to_a.sort_by { |e| e[1][1] }.map(&:first)
end

def redithion(str)
    str.chars.map { |e|
        first_index = str.index(e)
        [first_index, str.index(e,first_index+1)]
    }.map{|e| e[1].nil? ? str.length + 1 : e[1]}
     .select{|e| e < str.length }.uniq.sort.map {|e| str[e]}
end
```

```
def sawa(str)
  str.each_char.with_object([{}, []]) do
    |c, (h, a)| h[c] ? a.push(c) : h.store(c, true)
  end.last.uniq
end

def stefan_1(str)
  str.each_char.select.with_index { |c, i| str[0, i].count(c) == 1 }
end

def stefan_2(str)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char.with_object([]) do |c, a|
    a << c if h[c] == 1
    h[c] += 1
  end
end

def stefan_3(str)
  h = Hash.new(0)
  str.each_char.select { |c| (h[c] += 1) == 2 }
end

def cary(str)
  read1, read2 = Set.new, Set.new
  str.each_char { |c| read2.add(c) unless read1.add?(c) }
  read2.to_a
end
```

```
str = "Jack be nimble, jack be quick, Jack jumped over the candle stick"

compare(
  { sschmeck:   -> { sschmeck  str },
    drenmi:     -> { drenmi    str },
    redithion:  -> { redithion str },
    sawa:       -> { sawa      str },  
    stefan_1:   -> { stefan_1  str },  
    stefan_2:   -> { stefan_2  str },  
    stefan_3:   -> { stefan_3  str },  
    cary:       -> { cary      str }}
)

stefan_3 is faster than stefan_1 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
stefan_1 is similar to stefan_2
stefan_2 is faster than sawa by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
sawa is similar to cary
cary is faster than sschmeck by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
sschmeck is faster than drenmi by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
drenmi is similar to redithion
```

For:

```
str = "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to Heaven, we were all going direct the other way – in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only."
str.size #=>613
```

we obtain:

```
Running each test 16 times. Test will take about 1 second.
stefan_3 is faster than sawa by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
sawa is similar to stefan_2
stefan_2 is similar to drenmi
drenmi is similar to cary
cary is faster than sschmeck by 60.00000000000001% ± 1.0%
sschmeck is faster than stefan_1 by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
stefan_1 is faster than redithion by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
```

My takeaway is that the results are close enough that the choice of method should depend on other factors. I tested for readability with a stopwatch, stopping the timer when I thought, "Oh, I see." I won that, but of course I already understood what I was reading. `stefan_3`, which clocked `0.3` seconds, was next. I figured out `sawa` at `1:23:14`.

Comment: Probably depends on string length, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a trivial solution to this, but here's one that could serve as a starting point. It works by keeping a reference to the index of all occurrences of a character.

Example using the string `"abba"`:

```
str = "abba"

char_map = str.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }).with_index { |(c, m), i| m[c] << i }
#=> {"a"=>[0, 3], "b"=>[1, 2]}
```

We now have a hash with each character as a key, and the indices of their occurrences as values. We can now filter out the non-duplicates, and sort the rest by their second occurrence:

```
char_map.select { |_, v| v.length > 1 }.to_a.sort_by { |e| e[1][1] }.map(&:first)
#=> ["b", "a"]
```

And the complete implementation:

```
def repeated(str)
  str.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }).with_index { |(c, m), i| m[c] << i }.select { |_, v| v.length > 1 }.to_a.sort_by { |e| e[1][1] }.map(&:first)
end

repeated("abba")
#=> ["b", "a"]

repeated("Pippi")
#=> ["p", "i"]

repeated("limbojackassin the garden")
#=> ["a", "s", "i", " ", "e", "n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def repeated(str)
    return str.chars.map { |e|
        first_index = str.index(e)
        [first_index, str.index(e,first_index+1)]
    }.map{|e| e[1].nil? ? str.length + 1 : e[1]}
     .select{|e| e < str.length }.uniq.sort.map {|e| str[e]}
end
```

**Example:**

```
repeated('Pippi')
=> ["p", "i"]
```

**Explanation:**

It basically gets the two first indexes of each character, it removes the characters that weren't repeated (second index is null), then gets the second indexes, makes an uniq, sorts ascending and map those indexes to the corresponding character from the string.